# Storing Images in MongoDB w/o using GridFS

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, rest

A web application feature I'm working on allows users to upload an image along with some form data. We're working under the assumption that the image file will not exceed 16MB and so GridFS can be disregarded (for now).

On my React + Flux front-end I am utilising the FileReader object to read the image file as a binary string which I then append to my request object. It's a pretty ugly but it works...

My Node.js backend receives said object and is inserted into my MongoDB datastore. The image is set to 'BinData' data type in my schema which represents binary data. When a request is initiated to retrieve document X that contains image Y the request is slow, but manageable for single document retrieval as we're are only handling one buffer array with a base64 encoding that is converted on the client which.

Now I have attempted to retrieve multiple documents of this type, however the request is taking dreadfully long. To set the context, a single request for 4 documents around 1MB in size (about 996kb of binary data representing the image) takes about 6 seconds.

Now obviously I can add pagination to reduce the load but starting with response times for only 4 documents is like fighting an uphill battle. There doesn't seem to be much guidance on this matter as many of the Stackoverflow questions relate to storing images but not actually receiving them at reasonable speed.

The underlying problem is retrieving multiple documents, each containing a single image. Is there an intuitive way of storing and receiving image files with my current stack to improve response times?

If complete refactoring of my implementation is required, what would be an optimal solution for this type of scenario? E.g. User uploads information + image, store data, retrieve multiple instances across many users at once.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This would be a fair question if it only showed the code currently in use and stuck to the problem at hand. So it's really missing the code for context. It also sounds like you are trying to send all data including images in the data packet ( does mention base64 encoding ) which depending on the context might not be the optimal approach. That example is since most browsers will cache content ( such as images from urls ) it's probably best to do so. But real context would benefit from a working example. As it is we'd just be guessing. Title could do with some work as well.

Comment: FYI the [tag:nosql] is probably one of the most useless tags you could put on your question. So removed. Not really sold on the usefulness of [tag:rest] either, since you are likely hitting most of your audience with just the [tag:javascript] and [tag:mongodb] tags.

Comment: @BlakesSeven I've explained my problem sufficiently and so my code is not required as the context has been set otherwise. Also, the code isn't issue seeing as you missed that fact.

Comment: @BlakesSeven Also, I am requesting assistance regarding how I should implement what I'm trying to achieve which was clearly stated at the end of my post. The context I provided was illustrating the inefficiency of my solution. 

FYI I added the 'nosql' tag so I could widen my audience to those who may have specific knowledge on how such files could be optimally stored in a nosql data store, so I disagree with you on that one.

Comment: Did you measure the time that the request takes to return to the browser, or the time until the image was displayed? You need to profile your problem. My guess: Since you are using rest, you are asking the browser to parse a huge JSON blob ... delay #1.  Then you are creating some kinds of buffers with base64 data and passing these around to DOM nodes ... delay #2.  Finally the browser is interpreting base64.  Since that's not the modern way of doing things some browsers (e.g. FF) are no longer optimising this and we're seeing slow times on rendering base64... delay #3.